# How to cycle through colors rapidly on a CAShapeLayer?

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

> **Question:**
>
> The below code cycles through colors rapidly on a `CAShapeLayer()`. It
>   works fine, but it warms up the device. Is there a better and more
>   efficient way to cycle through colors rapidly on a `CAShapeLayer()`?

***Part 1.***

The below code draws, as an example, a square shape `UIBezierPath()`, and fills the layer `CAShapeLayer()`.

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0))
path.closePath()

let shape = CAShapeLayer()
shape.path = path.CGPath
shape.fillColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
```

***Part 2.***

Next, I add a `CAKeyframeAnimation` animation to the `CAShapeLayer()` which effectively cycles through colors in rapid succession, giving a multicolor flashing image effect, example image below.

```
let colorsAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "fillColor")

colorsAnimation.values = [UIColor.redColor().CGColor, UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor, UIColor.greenColor().CGColor, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor]

colorsAnimation.keyTimes = [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]
colorsAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationLinear
colorsAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false
colorsAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
colorsAnimation.duration = 0.5
colorsAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity

shape.addAnimation(colorsAnimation, forKey: nil)
```

**Image:**

[image]

Comment: Try calculationMode `kCAAnimationDiscrete`, currently your linear tries to interpolate colors, and discrete won't do that. That said not sure if you can do any better?

Comment: Thanks, @Alistra. I did try `kCAAnimationDiscrete` but it doesn't offer a smooth change between colors as the `kCAAnimationLinear` seems to. I think my image is somewhat misleading. Your suggestion did however get me thinking more about exactly what it is I'm trying to achieve, so thanks!

Comment: Just use more colors in the array and don't interpolate

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit lengthy but, this is how I do it in my app (phone should't get warm, at least mine does not):

```
var colorArray = [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue, UIColor.yellow, UIColor.orange, UIColor.green, UIColor.cyan, UIColor.purple]

var colorIndex = 0
var shouldStop = false

func sequenceA () {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, delay: 0.2, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {

        shape.fillColor = colorArray[colorIndex].CGColor

    }, completion: {finished in

        print(colorArray[colorIndex])

        if colorIndex == colorArray.count - 1 {
            colorIndex = 0
        }
        colorIndex+=1
        sequenceB()

    })
}

func sequenceB () {

    // When you want to stop
    if shouldStop == true {
        return
    }


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, delay: 0.2, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {

        shape.fillColor = colorArray[colorIndex].color


    }, completion: {finished in

        print(colorArray[colorIndex])

        if colorIndex == colorArray.count - 1 {
            colorIndex = 0
        }
        colorIndex+=1
        sequenceA()

    })
}


sequenceA()
```

To initate just call sequenceA or B and it will lock itself into a repeating process that switches the colors. When you want to stop, you can just set shouldStop to true.

You can change the speed of the color switching to whatever you want by changing the delay in both functions and switch the color types to whatever you wish as well. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, @Garret Kaye. This could work, but I was actually after a smooth change between colors which my image does not show. Sorry. From my other reading now, I believe the only way to achieve a smooth fill change of a `CAShapeLayer` is only through a `CAKeyframeAnimation`. But your suggestion too however did get me thinking more and revisit what it is I'm trying to achieve, so thanks!